# Powershell Get Value from PsCustomObject

Tags: powershell

I need some help on this:

I've got a [pscustomobject] that contains the below results, get from a xml file

```
Files                                           Session    
-----                                           -------    
{IMG_0518.JPG, IMG_0520.JPG, VG_Overview.mp4, } VG_Overview
```

I need to get the duplicated values on Files, e get it's respective session value:

My code to get the duplicated values: $trse is my [pscustomobject]

```
  $trse | ForEach-Object {$_.Files.Where({ $_ -ne ""})} | Group | Where-Object{$_.Count -gt 1} | Select @{Name="Files";Expression={$_.Name}},@{Name="Session";Expression={$_.Session}},@{Name="Occurrences";Expression={$_.Count}}
```

and the results are this:

```
    Files               Session Occurrences
    -----               ------- -----------
    GC7_Gender.WAV                      2
    NG6_Gender.WAV                      2
    NG9_Gender_I.WAV                    2
    NG9_Gender_II.WAV                   2
    VG4_Gender.WAV                      2
```

And i need to get this:

```
    Files               Session Occurrences
    -----               ------- -----------
    GC7_Gender.WAV      VG_Over         2
    NG6_Gender.WAV      Gh_tre          2
    NG9_Gender_I.WAV    FG_iop          2
    NG9_Gender_II.WAV   VB_jkl          2
    VG4_Gender.WAV      ER_uilv         2
```

Thanks a lot for any help on this, i think the problem is when i get de duplicated files, i lost the session values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably easier to understand if we re-format your code slightly:

```
$trse | ForEach-Object { 
    $_.Files.Where( { $_ -ne "" } ) 
} | Group | Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } | Select @{Name = "Files"; Expression = { $_.Name } }, @{Name = "Session"; Expression = { $_.Session } }, @{Name = "Occurrences"; Expression = { $_.Count } }
```

`ForEach-Object` outputs *only* the `Files` values, so by the time we reach `Group`, any relationship between the file names and the corresponding `Session` value has been lost.

Move the `Group | Where | Select` chain inside the `ForEach-Object` block:

```
$trse | ForEach-Object {
    $Session = $_.Session
    $_.Files.Where( { $_ -ne "" } ) | Group | Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } | Select @{Name = "Files"; Expression = { $_.Name } }, @{Name = "Session"; Expression = { $Session } }, @{Name = "Occurrences"; Expression = { $_.Count } } 
}
```

---

#### Bonus tip:

For the calculated property expressions that just rename existing properties, you can supply the input property name as the `Expression` value, no need to supply a scriptblock:

```
... |Select @{Name = "Files"; Expression = 'Name' }, @{Name = "Session"; Expression = { $Session } }, @{Name = "Occurrences"; Expression = 'Count' }
```

Comment: great bonus...didn't know that!

Comment: Nice! That´s it! Thanks once again @Mathias, for the solution and explanation. You in your best.